# React Native using setState with setParams

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a react native app where I'd like to be able to change the state from the static navigationOptions. I was following this: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1789

And have implemented one of the solutions as follows:

```js
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const { state } = navigation;
    const {params = {}} = navigation.state;
    navigation.params = {title: "", description: "", points: 0, image: {}, saveImage: true};
    return {
      headerRight: ( <Button transparent onPress={()=> params.create()}><Icon name="ios-add" style={{color: 'white'}}/></Button>)
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        create: this.openCreateModal
    });
  }

  openCreateModal() {
    this.setState({createModalVisible:true});
  }
```

Unfortunately when I call the openCreateModal function by pressing the button, I get the error `this.setState is not a function`.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `openCreateModal()` method is not bound. [Look further down](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1789#issuecomment-366890244) in that issue and someone points out that mistake.

To fix this, you either need to explicitly bind it so it has access to the correct `this` context, for example in your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.openCreateModal = this.openCreateModal.bind(this);
}
```

Or you can convert it to an ES6 arrow function which would auto-bind it to the class's context like so:

```
openCreateModal = () => {
  this.setState({createModalVisible:true});
}
```